# flexible handling of decimal representation in rails number_field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, decimal

The Rails [form tag helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) is particularly useful, as it validates by brute force the numericality of a value client-side.

However, if I am not mistaken, this relies on browser conventions with respect to the `step` atttribute

```
<input min="0" max="10" step="any" type="number" name="landing[arrival_radius]" id="landing_arrival_radius">
```

The browser is set to the inderlying device's system definitions for decimals, thus restricting the symbol used for a decimal.

Server-side, a sanitiser will `gsub` commas for periods (the min/max ranges are below the 1000s), given the application settings.

What is unclear is the testing of the decimal input.  One cannot input `3,78` on a system that has the period as a decimal; it is considered 'not a number'.  Yet it is valid input in a large swath of the planet.

So how can this test be materially (St. Thomas syndrome) run? (Not just in the test suite)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, one can select regions/languages **per application**.
Thus a distinct browser can be used for such purposes.

The most interesting aspect is that this was tested with a Chromium browser (Opera) where it allowed use of both commas and periods (Firefox for period decimals considers commas text).  The parameters received by the application were all with a decimal period; no sanitising was required.